# Как сделать так, чтобы нули были после единиц, а не пропадали?

Tags: сортировка, ассемблер

Возникла проблема с кодом на ассемблере. Дана двухбайтовая ячейка памяти, в которой записана последовательность нулей и единиц. Нужно сделать так, чтобы в последовательности сначала шли единицы, а потом нули.

Проблема в том, что данный код, приведенный внизу, оставляет только единицы. Нули исчезают просто. Хотелось бы понять: как сделать так, чтобы нули не только бы показывались, но и стояли после единиц?

```
mov bx, 0 // Заносит в регистр bx число 0
mov ax, chislo // Заносит в регистр ax число i
mov cx, 16 // Счетчик (16)
m1: // цикл m1
    shl ax, 1 // логический сдвиг влево
    adc bx, 0 // 
    loop m1 //
    cmp bx, 0; //если единиц нет
jz  m2 //
    mov cx, bx //
    m0 : // цикл m0
shl ax, 1 // логический сдвиг влево
    shr ax, 0
    add ax, 1 //
    loop m0 //
    m2 :
mov s, ax
```

Comment: Что такое "сначала"? Где находится начало? Старшие биты или младшие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит "нули пропадают"? O_o

Ваш код совершенно корректно "собирает" все исходные единицы в младших разрядах 16-битного регистра `ax`, а исходные нули, соответственно - в старших разрядах этого регистра.

Команда `shr ax, 0` в вашем коде бессмысленна и ничего не делает. А в остальном все работает нормально. Ничего никуда не пропадает.

А уж где у вас должно быть "начало": в старших битах или в младших - это уже у вас надо спрашивать.

В вашей версии достаточно заменить последний цикл на

```
m0: 
  shr ax, 1
  add ax, 8000h
  loop m0
```

и единицы окажутся в старших битах

---

Для решения этой задачи можно применить специальные процессорные инструкции и битовые хаки... но "лобовое" решение я бы сделал так

```
__asm
{
  mov ax, chislo
  xor bx, bx
shift:
  shl ax, 1
  jnc skip
  rcl bx, 1 // `rcr` для старших битов
skip:
  jnz shift
  mov s, bx
}
```

А вот с инструкцией `popcnt` все проще

```
__asm
{
  popcnt cx, chislo
  mov ax, 1
  shl ax, cl
  dec ax
  mov s, ax
}
```

а для старших битов добавить `ror ax, cl` после `dec ax`.

Comment: Спасибо вам за исправление последнего цикла! Программа заработала. Там была проблема в том, что итоговое число состояло только из единиц. А исправление цикла m0 решило эту проблему. Единицы - старшие биты.

Comment: @MikeTaylor если ответ вам помог проголосуйте за него (стрелки слева) и отметьте как принятый (галочка ниже стрелок).